# How do I proceed with this?

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\prod_{k=1}^K\sum_{m=1}^M\left[\frac{bk^3n^5-cm^2}{n^2+ak^4}\right]$$

I must make it work in a C programme , for my C class , and we will give number for the $a, b ,c , N , M, K$ in the programme.

But how will I write it? First the addition then the multiplication , and then the outer addition ?

I dont want the answer to how to write the programme , but how to analyze this ?

Comment: are you familiar with for loop ?

Comment: That is right. First addition by varying $m$, for given $a,b,c,n, M, k$. Then multiplication by varying $k$, for given $a,b,c,n,M, K$. Finally addition by varying $n$ for given $a,b,c,N,M,K$.

Comment: Are you wondering how to interpret this? (What order to take the sums and products?)

Comment: @edcharlie yes , i know for loop , and i know that if i had only addition I would use for loop , but this is a bit more complicated for me

Comment: @user8734617 thank you , now i think i know what i should do to write this programme

Comment: @Useless yes , but if it is how user8734617 told me , then i think my question about the order is answered

Comment: The innermost sum can be calculated explicitly but there is no further simplification for general values of $a,b,c$.